# Mysql - need help for my query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like below

```
Date         Name  Type  Tax_Type  Amount  Tax    Total
12/03/2016   1     0     14.5      100     12.66  100
12/03/2016   2     1     3.5       200     7      207
12/03/2016   3     1     2         300     6      306
12/03/2016   1     0     14.5      400     50.66  400
12/03/2016   1     0     2         500     9.8    500
12/03/2016   2     1     3.5       600     21     621
12/03/2016   4     1     14.5      700     101.5 801.5
```

Here the "Type" is Inclusive as 0 and Exclusive as 1 in percentage
now I want like this

```
Type      Tax_Type  Sum of Tax
0         14.5      63.32
0         3.5       0
0         2         9.8
1         14.5      101.5
1         3.5       29
1         2         6
```

Kindly help me.

Comment: Kindly share what you have tried.

Comment: Seems to be a pretty simple `sum()` with `group by` on the non-summed fields. `Select sum(field1), field2, field3 from table group by field2, field3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. Select the desired columns, and group by them:

```
SELECT `Type`, `Tax_Type`, SUM(`Tax`) FROM `table` GROUP BY `Type`,`Tax_Type` ORDER BY `Type`
```